# How to submit form through jQuery onblur

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

So I am trying to submit the form through jQuery onblur (i.e. As soon as the focus leaves the password field, form submits through jQuery). There are similar questions but it's not what I am looking for. I tried using the document.getElementById but it isn't working.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
<script>
    $(function(){
       $("#pswd").blur({
          $("#myForm").submit(); 
       });

    });

</script>
```

Comment: assuming selectors are correct and they exist when code runs this should work. What is happening? Any errors in your browser console?

Comment: First off there is an error, especially the way the blur function is written... it should be `$("#pswd").blur(function(){ ...`

Answer (score 2):

As @dvenkatsagar suggested, you have some syntax errors,

Live Preview: http://codepen.io/larryjoelane/pen/VedXqr

```
(function($){

       //I selected the body tag first because I do not know if you are creating
       //the pswd element dynamically
       $("body").on("blur","#pswd",function(e){


          $("#myForm").submit(); 


       });

      })(jQuery);
```

It is not necessary but I changed the way your closure was structured just in case you want to use other libraries in the future inside your closure besides jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Well the only problem I can see the function blur() and the way it is written, I think you should change it like this:

```
$(function(){
   $("#pswd").on("blur",function(){
      $("#myForm").submit(); 
   });

})();
```